# Scale in FastReport.Net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, fastreport

I would like to set the scale mode property of the preview(FastReport.Net mvc) control programmatically.

I accomplish that by this method But I Recieve This Error:

> *The type 'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.*

```
webReport.Report.Preview.ZoomPageWidth();
```

Comment: So...did you add a reference to System.Windows.Forms, specifically version 4.0.0.0 to your solution/project?  The error message is pretty straightforward here.

Comment: I know That But I use Asp.net Mvc Why Use Win form reference??? is any other method whitout need Win reference ???

Comment: I couldn't say, but if the plugin has a reference to .NET items in that assembly, you have to include a reference to it.  WebGrease (another plugin used to minify css and js) also has the same reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: It is Not Logical To Use Application Dll in Web.

Comment: Then don't use the plugin.  Just because the namespace doesn't sound right to you doesn't mean you can't or shouldn't use it.  You have your answer, unfortunately, either add the reference and continue to use this plugin, or don't :/

Comment: No I am sure That It Have Another Way Coding Or Other Solution For Web.but I Dont Know IT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way I handle This by this Code:

**First Solution**

webReport.Zoom = 0.85f;

**Second Solution**

webReport.Height = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(95);